# App not responding, unable to finish activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I have three activities for a game. The first is a menu, the second is the game activity, and the final is the game-over page which shows the player's score. When I get to the final activity, pressing the back button renders the application unresponsive.

I get an unusual message in LogCat:

```
07-26 19:09:30.756: I/dalvikvm(3223): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
07-26 19:09:31.396: I/dalvikvm(3223): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

I opened this stack traces file, but I am unable to pinpoint any errors as the file is very long.

Upon searching this message, I found two SO questions pertaining to it; one unanswered and the other without a clear resolution.

Here are the parts of my code that I believe are relevant:

**First activity does nothing but set the layout in onCreate and contain an event listener for the start button, so it is not the problem.**

Second activity starts the **game loop.** To end this activity and start the final one, I use the following method:

```
public void endGame() {
    scheduleTaskExecutor.shutdownNow();

    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();

    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(EndGameActivity.PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    if (level > settings.getInt("highLevel", 0)) {
        editor.putInt("highLevel", level);
        editor.commit();
    }

    if (zombiesKilled > settings.getInt("highscore", 0)) {
        editor.putInt("highscore", zombiesKilled);
        editor.commit();
    }

    Looper.prepare();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             GameActivity.activity.finish();
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, EndGameActivity.class);
             context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    Looper.loop();
}
```

The `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` starts new levels, so it can be shut down. The timer is for spawning and rendering new enemies so it should be canceled as well.

The thread is stopped via `surfaceDestroyed` in its corresponding `SurfaceView`.

In my final activity, I pull the two values seen in the `endGame` method using `SharedPreferences` and set them as `TextView`s:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.endgame_layout);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    highscore = settings.getInt("highscore", 0);

    highscoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore);
    highscoreText.setText("Most zombies ever killed is " + highscore);

    totalZombiesKilled = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalZombiesKilled);
    totalZombiesKilled.setText("This time you killed " + GameLoop.zombiesKilled);

    highLevel = settings.getInt("highLevel", 0);

    highLevelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highLevelText);
    highLevelText.setText("Your highest level is " + highLevel);

    sessionLevelText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    sessionLevelText.setText("This time you survived " + GameLoop.level + " levels");
}
```

**It should be noted that if I end the game activity without starting the final activity, every works fine and I am brought back to the menu with no problems. There are only issues when I start the final activity then try to press the back button to go to the menu.**

If anything more is required for you to assist me, notify me and I will post whatever you require.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    "RILReceiver" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2dd5aa0 self=0xb71c8db0
  | sysTid=579 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1222864376
  | state=S schedstat=( 530000000 2610000000 446 ) utm=43 stm=10 core=0
  #00  pc 00021268  /system/lib/libc.so (recvmsg+8)
  #01  pc 0006bcbd  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #02  pc 0006c12d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #03  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #04  pc 0004deff  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
  #05  pc 0003873d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+8)
  #06  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #07  pc 0002df34  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
  #08  pc 0002b5cc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
  #09  pc 00060319  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
  #10  pc 0006033d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
  #11  pc 0005502b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #12  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #13  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:33)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:98)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.RIL.readRilMessage(RIL.java:421)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.RIL.access$400(RIL.java:215)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.RIL$RILReceiver.run(RIL.java:521)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"RILSender" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2dd3560 self=0xb71c7180
  | sysTid=578 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1222875912
  | state=S schedstat=( 370000000 2140000000 714 ) utm=18 stm=19 core=0
  #00  pc 000215cc  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
  #01  pc 00010627  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+98)
  #02  pc 00010851  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
  #03  pc 00069ff1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
  #04  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
  #05  pc 0004deff  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
  #06  pc 0003873d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCheckCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+8)
  #07  pc 00000214  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2db7a90 self=0xb71ad658
  | sysTid=552 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1222978544
  | state=S schedstat=( 370000000 1570000000 660 ) utm=26 stm=11 core=0
  #00  pc 00020418  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002c0ef  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001d375  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001da7f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
  #04  pc 0001db15  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
  #05  pc 000218dd  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #06  pc 0000ea45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #07  pc 0004cd79  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
  #08  pc 0000e577  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #09  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #10  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2db79a0 self=0xb71ac9e8
  | sysTid=551 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1222981728
  | state=S schedstat=( 440000000 5620000000 682 ) utm=27 stm=17 core=0
  #00  pc 00020418  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002c0ef  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001d375  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001da7f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
  #04  pc 0001db15  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
  #05  pc 000218dd  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #06  pc 0000ea45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #07  pc 0004cd79  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
  #08  pc 0000e577  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #09  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #10  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=8 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2db3e10 self=0xb71ab3c8
  | sysTid=539 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1222985696
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 100000000 55 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0xb2b17370> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject(Daemons.java:230)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:207)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2db3c60 self=0xb71aaa98
  | sysTid=538 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1222988048
  | state=S schedstat=( 100000000 360000000 205 ) utm=7 stm=3 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0xb2b02718> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2db3af8 self=0xb71aa168
  | sysTid=537 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1222990400
  | state=S schedstat=( 40000000 250000000 208 ) utm=1 stm=3 core=0
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0xb2b02640> 
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
  at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:130)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2db3a08 self=0xb71a9d10
  | sysTid=536 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1223997408
  | state=S schedstat=( 1160000000 3970000000 1288 ) utm=62 stm=54 core=0
  #00  pc 00021794  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 0000ed94  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 0000edf4  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
  #03  pc 000739bb  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 0005470d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #05  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #06  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2db3920 self=0xb70b41c0
  | sysTid=534 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1224000640
  | state=S schedstat=( 70000000 280000000 28 ) utm=5 stm=2 core=0
  #00  pc 00020568  /system/lib/libc.so (select+20)
  #01  pc 00061227  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #02  pc 00063d65  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #03  pc 0005470d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #05  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2db3828 self=0xb70b3500
  | sysTid=533 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1224004304
  | state=R schedstat=( 1230000000 2830000000 460 ) utm=65 stm=58 core=0
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xb2db3748 self=0xb70b2880
  | sysTid=532 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=-1224241520
  | state=S schedstat=( 550000000 2150000000 7279 ) utm=4 stm=51 core=0
  #00  pc 00021794  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 0000ed94  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 0000edf4  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
  #03  pc 0007243f  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #04  pc 0005470d  /system/lib/libdvm.so
  #05  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #06  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

----- end 528 -----


----- pid 53 at 2014-07-26 18:52:05 -----
Cmd line: /system/bin/mediaserver

"mediaserver" sysTid=53
  #00  pc 00020418  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002c0ef  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001d375  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001da7f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
  #04  pc 0001db15  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
  #05  pc 00001b93  /system/bin/mediaserver
  #06  pc 0000e23b  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
  #07  pc 000015e8  /system/bin/mediaserver

"mediaserver" sysTid=112
  #00  pc 00020158  /system/lib/libc.so (read+12)
  #01  pc 00014117  /system/lib/hw/camera.goldfish.so (android::EmulatedCameraHotplugThread::threadLoop()+50)
  #02  pc 0000ea45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #03  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #04  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

"ApmTone" sysTid=114
  #00  pc 00021798  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+12)
  #01  pc 0000ed94  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 00019d91  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
  #03  pc 00027a2b  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
  #04  pc 0000ea45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #05  pc 0000e577  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #06  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #07  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

"ApmAudio" sysTid=115
  #00  pc 00021798  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+12)
  #01  pc 0000ed94  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 00019d91  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
  #03  pc 00027a2b  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
  #04  pc 0000ea45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #05  pc 0000e577  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #06  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #07  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

"ApmOutput" sysTid=116
  #00  pc 00021798  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+12)
  #01  pc 0000ed94  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 00019d91  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
  #03  pc 00027a2b  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
  #04  pc 0000ea45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #05  pc 0000e577  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #06  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #07  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

"AudioOut_2" sysTid=119
  #00  pc 00021794  /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
  #01  pc 0000ed94  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
  #02  pc 0000edf4  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
  #03  pc 00019d59  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
  #04  pc 0001bad1  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so
  #05  pc 0000ea45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #06  pc 0000e577  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #07  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #08  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

"Binder_1" sysTid=121
  #00  pc 00020418  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002c0ef  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001d375  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001da7f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
  #04  pc 0001db15  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
  #05  pc 000218dd  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #06  pc 0000ea45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #07  pc 0000e577  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #08  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #09  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

"Binder_2" sysTid=428
  #00  pc 00020418  /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
  #01  pc 0002c0ef  /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
  #02  pc 0001d375  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
  #03  pc 0001da7f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
  #04  pc 0001db15  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
  #05  pc 000218dd  /system/lib/libbinder.so
  #06  pc 0000ea45  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
  #07  pc 0000e577  /system/lib/libutils.so
  #08  pc 0000d060  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
  #09  pc 0000d1f8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
```

Comment: Post the contents of /data/anr/traces.txt, or at least the final crash in it.  You're crashing in C code and that file will give more details.

Comment: @GabeSechan There are over 2,000 lines in it... Do you want me to post all of that..?

Comment: No, the last crash would be enough.  But that file holds the C crash logs on your device, without the crash we can't really say more than that some C component (which may even be an OS component) crashed.  If you can't tell that, post the last 200 or so lines and we'll figure it out and ask for more if needed.

Comment: @GabeSechan I posted the last couple hundred lines... Apologies, but I know nothing about C or this stack trace file.

Comment: I need you to go up a little further.  Look for a line that says SIGSEGV or something like that.  That should be the first line of the crash.

Comment: @GabeSechan There is no such line... You refer to the issue as a "crash" when the app doesn't exactly crash, it just displays a dialog prompting me to either wait or shutdown the unresponsive app... Could this be the reason? I tried to post the rest of the file up to a certain line that seemed to be the start of that specific stack trace, but it exceeded the character limit by some 17,000 characters.

Comment: Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'   That line only occurs when a C component has caused a signal to the linux kernel that is unrecoverable.  In short, a crash.

Comment: @GabeSechan Oh ok... Well there is definitely no SIGSEGV line (searched the file).

Comment: Here's an idea-  lets wipe out that file, cause this crash again, and grab it immediately.  Then the only crash in it is this one

Comment: @GabeSechan I wiped the file and it wrote another 2,000-something lines in it. They all have the same time in the heading as well... It would appear that all 2,000 lines are a result of the same crash.

Comment: Then post it somewhere else online and put a link to it back here.

Comment: @GabeSechan Try [this](http://www.docdroid.net/f9rv/traces.txt.html)

Comment: Ok, so they gave us the nastiest form of crash.  I assume there was nothing else in the normal logcat?  So what I'm getting from the crash is a list of where every thread in your app has on its stack.  I see a lot of waits and select calls.  These are normal-  it means the threads are waiting for data or commands.  I'm wondering about the possibility of a deadlock state causing the watchdog timer to go off.

Comment: @GabeSechan Nothing else in LogCat. A deadlock is a possibility - let me check my code again and make sure I'm not doing anything that would obviously cause a deadlock.

Comment: @GabeSechan I solved my problem - there was one situation that could've potentially caused a deadlock, but the real problem was my handler. I had to add `getMainLooper()` and remove the other Looper methods to work on the UI thread, and I had to move the `finish()` method. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @ZachH You should write your solution as an answer to your question... that way it won't appear to be unanswered to people who stumble across your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my handler was actually being executed on a separate thread rather than the intended UI thread, as handlers run on the thread in which they're created. Rather than calling `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()`, I simply specified that the handler was to use the main thread's looper with `getMainLooper()`:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EndGameActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            GameActivity.activity.finish();
        }
    });
```

I also moved the call to `finish()` to prevent the activity from finishing before the new one had been created.